# Stata: Ado file syntax

Tags: stata

I am working with an .ado file named `flow`.   If the user types `flow i` I want one `if` statement to run.  If the user types `flow e`, I want another `if` statement to run.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many readers of this forum expect to see *some* code that you tried....

```
program flow 
    version 8  // will work on almost all Stata in current use 
    gettoken what garbage : 0 
    if "`what'" == "" | "`garbage'" != "" | !inlist("`what'", "e", "i")  { 
       di as err "syntax is flow e or flow i"
       exit 198 
    }

    if "`what'" == "e" { 
       <code for e>
    }
    else if "`what'" == "i" { 
       <code for i>
    } 
end
```

The last `if` condition is redundant as we've already established that the user typed `e` or `i`. Edit it out according to taste.

Comment: Thanks, I tried- `syntax [, i e]` but it obviously didn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

Given your comment on the answer by @NickCox, I assume you tried something like this:

```
program flow
    version 8
    syntax [, i e]
    if "`i'`e'" == "" {
        di as err "either the i or the e option needs to be specified"
        exit 198
    }
    if "`i'" != "" & "`e'" != "" {
        di as err "the i and e options cannot be specified together"
        exit 198
    }
    if "`e'" != "" {
        <code for e>
    }
    if "`i'" != "" {
        <code for i>
    }
end
```

After that you call `flow` like this: `flow, i` or `flow, e`. Notice the comma, this is now necessary (but not in the command by @NickCox) because you made them options.

Comment: My code was very similar to this, but the "E" and the "I" were always both running irrespective of the flow query, and I couldn't figure out why.  Your code works, though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `i` and `e` to be mutually exclusive options, then this is yet another alternative:

```
 program flow
    version 8
    capture syntax , e 

    if _rc == 0  { // syntax matched what was typed 
        <code for e>
    }
    else {
        syntax , i // error message and program exit if syntax is incorrect
        <code for i>
    }
end
```

If the code in each branch is at all long, many would prefer subprograms for each case as a matter of good style, but that would be consistent with the sketch here. Note that in each `syntax` statement  the option is declared compulsory.

The effect of `capture` is this: errors are not fatal, but are "eaten" by `capture`. So you need to look at the return code, accessible in `_rc`. 0 for `_rc` always means that the command was successful. Non-zero always means that the command was unsuccessful. Here, and often elsewhere, there are only two ways for the command to be right, so we don't need to know what `_rc` was; we just need to check for the other legal syntax.

Note that even my two answers here differ in style on whether a user typing an illegal command gets an informative error message or just "invalid syntax". The context to this is an expectation that every Stata command comes with a help file. Some programmers write on the assumption that the help file explains the syntax; others want their error messages to be as helpful as possible.